# C++, return const and non const reference to std::set item

Tags: c++, reference, set, constants

There is the class A containing two overloaded methods getItems();

```
typedef std::vector <int> TItems;

template <typename T>
class A 
{
private:
    T a;
    TItems items;

public:
    A(){}
    A ( const T a_, const TItems & items_) : a(a_) , items (items_) {}
    bool operator () ( const A <T> &aa ) {return a < aa.a;}
    TItems const & getItems() const {return items}
    TItems & getItems() {return items}
};
```

and the set of A objects

```
template <typename T>
struct TSet {typedef std::set <A <T> > Type;};
```

I would like to return const reference / reference to TItems, but only the second method works

```
int main ()
{
TSet <double> ::Type t;
TSet <double> ::Type::iterator it = t.begin();
t.insert (A <double>( 5, TItems(10,10)));

const TItems *items = &(it->getItems()); //OK
TItems *items = &(it->getItems()); //Error  
}

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const TItems *' to 'TItems *
```

Is it the reason that non-constant references enables to modify A objects causing a potential rearrangement od the set? But items of the set are not arranged by A.items but by a.

Is there a way how modify A.items using a non-constant reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it the reason that non-constant references enables to modify A objects causing a potential rearrangement od the set?

Exactly. `std::set`'s elements (and BTW `std::map`'s keys) are immutable, the structure will only give you const-qualified elements. So you have the option

- change your structure to `std::map` and put your `a` as key and `items` as data
- if you are absolutely sure you won't break the ordering by manipulation with `items`, you can `const_cast` (or declare `items` `mutable` if that suits you).

Comment: Technically `const_cast` is UB for this purpose (even if I'm guilty having used it in cases I was guaranteeing myself the ordering), and `mutable` doesn't change anything here. No, there is no way out: if you allow users to potentially break the ordering, you shouldn't be using `set` in the first place.

Comment: @AlexandreC. care to elaborate why undefined behaviour should happen if you remove const from the set elements and only change members that are not used for ordering? For example, you could declare members that are used for ordering as const. That doesn't mean the entire set element has to be const.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to change set elements, you may break the invariants of the structure implementing the set (eg. balanced search tree). Elements of sets must thus be immutable. So you must remove an element and replace it with a new one if you want to modify an element. In particular, you cannot expect a non-const reference through an iterator to `set` (if you could modify it, you could break the ordering).
.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the objects stored in a std::set because this would break the set invariants. Instead you could remove the object from the set then modify it and insert it again.

An other possibility is to use a std::map instead. The key of the map cannot be modified but the value can.

Comment: If you refer to the first option then you can make a copy, erase it from the set, modify that copy and insert it into the set.